# How to run a docker container that has docker running inside it?

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm building an app that makes api calls to run code inside docker containers

I want to run a docker container that has docker running inside it.

I want to create a docker file that pulls other docker images inside it and then waits for api calls (on port 2376) to create, run and delete containers based on the docker images that i pulled into the dockerfile

This is the dockerfile I'm trying to create right now.

```
FROM docker:stable

RUN docker pull python

EXPOSE 23788

CMD tail -f /dev/null
```

However when the RUN command is issued i get this error message:

```
docker: Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
```

I don't really know how to start docker inside a docker container.

The reason i need this kind of a docker file is so that i can then use kubernetes to scale this part of my application

Comment: You should use the Kubernetes API if you need to launch additional containers.  The Docker-in-Docker setup is particularly complex and I'd avoid using it.  In particular you can't use `docker pull` here because the (embedded) Docker daemon isn't running, and you can't start it because it requires settings you can't enable at build time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a special image for this, `docker:dind`. See the bit about "Docker in Docker" in https://hub.docker.com/_/docker.